# Ruby is disregarding string input from user-- converting strings to integers

Tags: ruby, calculator

```
print "How many miles are you driving? (number only) "
miles = gets.to_s.chomp

print "How expensive is gas per gallon? (just give a number) "
gas_price = gets.to_s.chomp

print "What type of car do you drive? "
car = gets.to_s.chomp.downcase


if car == "toyota"
  mpg = gets.to_s.chomp    
  mpg == 23
else 
  print "How many miles per gallon does your car get? "
  mpg = gets.to_s.chomp
  end


def gas_total(miles,gas_price,mpg)
  puts "Calculating the cost..."
  return (Integer(miles)/ Integer(mpg)) * Integer(gas_price)
  end

puts "It will cost you #{gas_total(miles,gas_price,mpg)} dollars"
```

So that is my code, everything works great except when I ask the question "What type of car do you drive". I can answer "toyota" but then I'm prompted again to type a number.

I want that when I type in "toyota", the computer processes it as I saying that the `mpg = 23`.

Also, is there a more efficient way than typing `mpg = gets.to_s.chomp` twice?

Comment: Don't indent `end` underneath the code in a block. Outdent it. Ruby != Python.

Comment: And why are you doing `mpg == 23`? That returns a true/false, it doesn't assign anything. Also, use `miles.to_i` instead of `Integer(miles)`; The same goes for the other `Integer(...)` uses.

Comment: `gets` means 'get a string' so using `.to_s` with `gets` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mpg = gets.to_s.chomp    
mpg == 23
```

Something is wrong here.  You are asking it to give you a value, then having an evaluation which returns true/false just sitting there.

I think you need to get rid of mpg = gets.chomp and turn mpg == 23 into mpg = 23.

Answer (score 0):

> I want that when you type in "toyota", the computer processes it as you saying that the mpg = 23.

Then in that case, why are you prompting for another number? Simply assign `mpg = 23` in that `if` block.